# installing new exhaust fan to exterior side of the wall

Tags: exhaust-fan

[image]Seeking advice from pro's who have installed a bathroom exhaust fan to exhaust air to the outside on the first floor bathroom on a two story home in Texas.

There are generally 2 ways to exhaust air from the first floor either through the roof access or through the wall exterior access. Both seem to work equally well. What is best practice for a first floor bathroom on a two story home?

Also if we decide to install a new outlet to exhaust this air through the side of the wall. What is best practice for this application? Core Drilling? Any good sealing methods recommended?

Comment: Usually the shortest path is the best.  Between floors usually have nice deep joists that a 3 or 4 inch duct can go though easy between joists.

Comment: I have added a picture of the project to show details. Thank you for any recommendations offered.

Answer (score 0):

Most direct route would be to use a wall mounted fan that directly exits through the wall. Next best, at least IMM and like crip659 said, is to use a ceiling mounted fan and run the exhaust duct between or through the floor joists. Obviously, this is easier if the floor joist are parallel to the direction the duct has to run.

I would not do a roof exhaust to the 2nd story roof unless there were no other options.  First of all that would be a lot of work running 3" duct through the wall up to the roof.  Second, I do not like making anymore roof penetrations than are absolutely necessary.

I did do a roof exhaust from a first floor powder room in a rancher.  But in that case there was no wall to use.  See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I have added a picture of the project to show details. Thank you SteveSh for any recommendations offered. I am assuming core drilling into the bricks to setup access for the duct work best way to go. Also what is best way to seal this after the setup is secured.

Comment: Do you need to use insulation duck work? Or foam spraying?